# Cert not due for renewal, but simulating renewal for dry run

Tags: python, ssl, centos6, centos6.5, certbot

I'm using certbot-auto generate certificate https for my domain name. I use command like this

```
sudo ./certbot-auto
```

it's ok, but when i renew certificate use command

```
sudo ./certbot-auto renew --dry-run
```

it can't renew certificate and show error message like below:

```
/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cryptography/__init__.py:26: DeprecationWarning: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of cryptography will drop support for Python 2.6
  DeprecationWarning
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.asia.conf
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cert not due for renewal, but simulating renewal for dry run
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
tls-sni-01 challenge for example.asia
tls-sni-01 challenge for www.example.asia
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Generating key (2048 bits): /etc/letsencrypt/keys/0020_key-certbot.pem
Creating CSR: /etc/letsencrypt/csr/0020_csr-certbot.pem
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates below have not been saved.)

Congratulations, all renewals succeeded. The following certs have been renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.asia/fullchain.pem (success)
** DRY RUN: simulating 'certbot renew' close to cert expiry
**          (The test certificates above have not been saved.)
```

Please help me

Comment: What exactly is the error? `--dry-run` is to simulate a renewal (it does not actually renew the certificate). You appear to have renewed the cert yesterday (Wed, 26 Oct 2016 02:49:00 UTC) and it doesn't expire for another 3 months. To renew a certificate, you wouldn't use the `--dry-run` option.

Comment: what command do we use for renew? please tell me

Comment: @AnandBhat, sorry sir, can i renew certificate before expire 3 month? after expire 3 month can i use this command  sudo ./certbot-auto renew --quiet for renew? is it ok?

Comment: I want to test renew certificate today. i use this command sudo ./certbot-auto renew --quiet  and sudo service httpd restart. the certificate can't renew for today (Thur, 27 Oct 2016 02:49:00 UTC)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command you ran in your question `sudo ./certbot-auto renew --dry-run` is used test renewal. As your log indicates, everything went well and the test was successful.

When you wish to renew the certificate, running `sudo ./certbot-auto renew --quiet` will work. You can renew certificates when they expire in less than 30 days or have already expired.

More details can be found in the [Certbot documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/all-instructions/) and [Certbot userguide](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewing-certificates).

Comment: Thanks you so much!  ./certbot-auto renew --quiet not working for me. i use sudo ./certbot-auto renew --force-renew is ok. but when i use crontab -e  * 15 * * *  /certbot-auto renew --force-renew   it have error like this: Bootstrapping dependencies for RedHat-based OSes...
yum is /usr/bin/yum
To use Certbot, packages from the EPEL repository need to be installed.
Please enable this repository and try running Certbot again. if know solution please help me